# Running log parser in a batch file issues with -i:EVT switch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, logparser

I am having unexpected errors while trying to execute a batch file using logparser.

I know that colons are used as labels in a batch file and that double colons are used for commenting. But what happens when a colon : appears in a switch like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %a in (servers.txt) do "C:\Program Files\Log Parser 2.2"\logparser -i:EVT "SELECT TimeGenerated,EventID,EventType,SourceName,ComputerName,Message FROM \\%a\%b WHERE TimeGenerated > TO_TIMESTAMP(SUB(TO_INT(SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP()),118800))AND EventID BETWEEN x AND y ORDER BY TimeGenerated DESC" -stats:OFF
```

If i run the logparser command directly, it runs fine. But run in a batch file is gives:

"EVT was unexpected at this time." How do I get cmd to interpret "-i:EVT" to be used as it would be outside a batch file?

How do I escape?

I have tried -i^:EVT and -i^^:EVT, both don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to duplicate the `For` variable `%` characters when you attempt to run it from an script, try this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (servers.txt) do "C:\Program Files\Log Parser 2.2"\logparser -i:EVT "SELECT TimeGenerated,EventID,EventType,SourceName,ComputerName,Message FROM \\%%a\%%b WHERE TimeGenerated > TO_TIMESTAMP(SUB(TO_INT(SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP()),118800))AND EventID BETWEEN x AND y ORDER BY TimeGenerated DESC" -stats:OFF
```

If your original code works fine ran from CMD then the modification would work ran from a script, anyways I will advise you that in this part `"C:\Program Files\Log Parser 2.2"\logparser` you've enclosed wrong the directory path, and also to avoid interpreter errors you would consider to agroupate the commands after the `DO` keyword like: `Do (This)`